# How do I clean deep burns in my oven?

Tags: oven, cleaning

So our apartment has an oven that, without fail, creates considerable smoke when we use it.  And we've been trying to clean it as best we can with baking soda and vinegar, along with Bon Amie powder cleanser, but we can't get it to come out.

Here's what the inside looks like:

[image]

[image]

Other than hours upon hours of scrubbing, is there anything we haven't tried yet that we could do to get these burn stains out?

Comment: 3M "Paint & Varnish Remover" disc (9413NA) in a portable drill and a paste of scouring powder and water. Remove the door for easier access, oven doors usually close to a slight open position, and then lift out of the hinge. Be careful of the hinge, it has a powerful spring (keep fingers away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trust you've already tried leaving a hot, wet (just water) cloth on it for a while, which may work if its sugar, as opposed to grease.

As long as your oven manual allows (it typically will, unless its a self-cleaning or continuous-cleaning oven), oven cleaner, which is basically caustics such as lye and solvents. Easy-off is a common brand in the US. Note, BTW, oven cleaner is one of the products where you actually want to read and beware the cautions on the side of the can.

Also, unless you actually see the black stuff on the bottom smoking, I'd guess its more likely to be the brown stuff everywhere else.